# Expand div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I searched these forums for a way to implement 'jquery expand div on click'

I found a simple and ideal tutorial but couldn't implement it when reinacting the code.

Is this code still valid with current jquery?  I believe I have replicated the demo exactly, just not sure about the link to the script.

Here is the tutorial I am working from [link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20144029/1471333]

```
[DEMO][2]

$('.wrapper').find('a[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.expand = !this.expand;
    $(this).text(this.expand?"Click to collapse":"Click to read more");
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.small, .big').toggleClass('small big');
});

[link [2]: http://jsfiddle.net/mWcmg/1/]
```

and here is my result at [link removed], where the demo resource file works, but my coding doesn't open, for whatever reason.  Perhaps the jquery I link to has changed?

*EDIT*
 here is a snippet of the HTML code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="small">
<p>Lorem..</p>
</div>
<a href="#">Click...</a>
</div>
```

Andy

Comment: Where's your relevant (minimal, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) HTML?

Comment: Thanks, but there's an '[edit]' link, just below your question's tags; click on that (or the one here in this comment) and add your HTML to your question (where it can be read, as opposed to your comment where it's illegible).

Comment: sorry, I've edited the initial question now.

Comment: So what is the problem. Code works as expected. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/mb7jL76k/

Comment: the tutorial code worked, but not my coding, the issue has been resolved by haul, below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27143926/1471333 thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your javascript inside the document ready event. Because in your example, you execute the javascript before the DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.wrapper').find('a[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.expand = !this.expand;
        $(this).text(this.expand?"Click to collapse":"Click to read more");
        $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.small, .big').toggleClass('small big');
    });
});
```

Comment: that's it, works fine now. thanks for the prompt response, impressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/v5kmoy1p/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="small">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<a id="click" href="#">Click...</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.small {
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.big {
    height: auto;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    $('div.wrapper').find('div').toggleClass('small big');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct so you could have forgotten to make the document ready (onDomready).

You can do that to put your code between `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapper').find('a[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.expand = !this.expand;
        $(this).text(this.expand?"Click to collapse":"Click to read more");
        $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.small, .big').toggleClass('small big');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes its right, JSfiddle by default have the ready function where as in monkeyshrine its does'nt

Comment: Why does my piece of code hasn't the colors like in other answers? I'm new to this website.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using jQuery you might as well take advantage of the features it offers. The toggle() method allows you to show/hide a component, with animations and everything that gives you. Here is an excerpt from a component I wrote that turns any div you specify into a collapsible pane with a title bar:

```
  CollapsiblePane.prototype.toggle = function( img ){
    var self = this, icon = ( ( self.selector.css( "display" ) === "none" ) ? "collapse" : "expand" );
  self.selector
     .toggle( 'blind', {}, 200, function(  ) {
        $( img ).attr( "src", self.path + "img/" + icon + ".png");
      });
  };
```

If you want to see the full source, you can see it here: https://github.com/robertdmunn/gadget-ui. There is a lot more going on than you need to see to illustrate what toggle() does, but if you want to get a sense of what you can do with jQuery to extend your UI components, take a look.

Comment: that sounds interesting Robert, do you have a link or fiddle where I can see this in action?

Comment: Link to working example of gadget-ui, including the CollapsiblePane object: http://jsfiddle.net/8q4n5z12/. If you have Bower installed, you can just 'bower install gadget-ui' to check out the source code and run the test page locally.